# Set segment equal width for SwiftUI Picker with SegmentedPickerStyle

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, picker

Using the `SegmentedPickerStyle` style `Picker` could make the control looks like `UISegmentedControl`. But I wonder how to adjust the segment width in the picker. For examle, the picker in the image has a different width for text.

Is there a way to make the segments the same width in the SwiftUI?

```swift
    Picker(selection: $store.utility.saliencyType, label: EmptyView()) {
        ForEach(Store.Utility.SaliencyType.allCases, id: \.self) { saliencyType in
            Text(saliencyType.text)
                .tag(saliencyType)
        }
    }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
```

[image]

Comment: It is macOS - only, on iOS all segments are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is default macOS NSSegmetedControl behavirour

```
@property NSSegmentDistribution segmentDistribution API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.13)); 
// Defaults to NSSegmentDistributionFill on 10.13, older systems will continue to behave similarly to NSSegmentDistributionFit
```

**Update:** here is workaround, based on finding `NSSegmentedControl` in run-time view hierarchy.

[image: demo]

**Disclaimer: Actually it is safe, ie. no crash in run-time, but can stop working in future returning to default behaviour.**

So, the idea is to inject `NSView` via representable into view hierarchy above (!!) `Picker`, as

```
Picker(selection: $store.utility.saliencyType, label: EmptyView()) {
        ForEach(Store.Utility.SaliencyType.allCases, id: \.self) { saliencyType in
            Text(saliencyType.text)
                .tag(saliencyType)
        }
    }
    .overlay(NSPickerConfigurator {                // << here !!
        $0.segmentDistribution = .fillEqually // change style !!
    })
    .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
```

and configurator itself

```
struct NSPickerConfigurator: NSViewRepresentable {
    var configure: (NSSegmentedControl) -> Void

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        let view = NSView()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let holder = view.superview?.superview {
                let subviews = holder.subviews
                if let nsSegmented = subviews.first?.subviews.first as? NSSegmentedControl {
                    self.configure(nsSegmented)
                }
            }
        }
        return view
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow. I'm a newbie to the Cocoa platform. First time to known about this behavior. And I think that it could be a great idea to override the global appearance of `NSSegmetedControl`. However, `UIAppearance` is the UIKit exclusive.

Comment: Interesting. You find a way to hook the underlying UI component. Good to known that trick.

Answer (score 3):

> ...For examle, the picker in the image has a different width for text.

In case you arrive here seeking for **iOS** SwiftUI SegmentedPickerStyle solution... I've found the iOS SwiftUI `.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())` will conform to global `UISegmentedControl.appearance()` settings, so I've used the following to successfully apportion the width of each segment:

```
UISegmentedControl.appearance().apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent = true
```

[image]

This is particularly useful if, for example, you want to support Dynamic Type fonts in your app, which can otherwise cause segments with longer names to blow out and get truncated. [aside: I also use this trick to change the SwiftUI segmented picker's font size! see [https://stackoverflow.com/a/71834578/3936065]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71834578/3936065)

Answer (score 0):

Ah the reach down to AppKit method.

Very clever indeed.
However this is not working for me, Monteray 12.3

Went to debug further using Xcode's Visual Debugger and I can see the NSPickerConfigurator class in the view hierarchy but no NSSegmetedControl.

It appears as if apple is clearing up NSViews from the hierarchy.

Time to think pure swiftui.