# SwiftUI Custom Font Size inside Picker using SegmentedPickerStyle

Tags: swiftui, font-size, picker

I am attempting to customize the font size of the two tags inside the Picker. I am using the SegmentedPickerStyle and I would like the Picker font size to match Text size of the other titles/strings that I am using on my form. The other fonts are using .font(.headline)

```
var body: some View {
NavigationView {
    ScrollView {
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            Group {
                Picker("", selection: $form.nameType) {
                    Text("First/Last name \(form.nameType == 0 ? "*" : "")").tag(0)
                    Text("Company name \(form.nameType == 1 ? "*" : "")").tag(1)
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can customize the font of your segment controllers adding this:

```
init() {
        UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(
            [
                .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18),
            ], for: .normal)
    }
```

Comment: What initializer is this for? The SwiftUI View?

Answer (score 2):

To expand on @Ludyem's correct answer, if in addition you'd like your SwiftUI SegmentedPickerStyle to support Dynamic Type fonts, then this should do the trick:

```
let font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .footnote) // regular weight
UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: font.pointSize, weight: .medium)], for: .normal) // medium weight
```

The default font for a UISegmentedControl appears to be systemFont(ofSize: 13) - which correspond to [UIFont.TextStyle.footnote](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/textstyle/1616700-footnote) - but **medium** weight. So the above gets the scaled (13pt) footnote font, and then adjust the weight to match.

Comment: This does not respond to dynamic type sizes. To confirm, run the code in a simulator and use the environment overrides to set the dynamic text size. Nothing changes. Would love to solve this issue.

Comment: If you wish to apply the change *dynamically*, ie at runtime, you may need to reapply it, triggered off the associated notification; see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontentsizecategory/1622948-didchangenotification